# What is a "lossy" cavity?

Tags: superconductivity, cavity-qed

I am studying cavity electrodynamics and superconducting qubits and the term "lossy" always comes up as in a lossy mode or a lossy cavity. If the qubits are superconducting, what is "lost"? I have googled the term and looked for papers but all I find is these terms being used without definition. Please help fellow physicists/engineers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loss $\approx$ coupling to another mode, usually a large number of modes and some times ones that are hard to individually control and observe. Mode is $\approx$ solution to Maxwell's equations. In an optical cavity made from two semi-transparent mirrors, some light can escape through the mirrors to become traveling waves propagating away from the cavity. From the point of view of the cavity mode itself, this is "loss". If the mirror surfaces have absorptive material on their surface (all mirrors have some amount of this, from e.g. water) or in their bulk, some light is absorbed in that surface or bulk thereby increasing the energy of the mirrors themselves. This too is called "loss".

Loss can be added intentionally or unintentionally. For example, the waves propagating out of the cavity may be intentional, so that we can couple the cavity light to something else. Any unwanted interaction between the cavity and anything else, no matter how weak, will eventually lead to some finite probability of energy leaking to an unwanted place.

Comment: Does that mean coupling of the mode with the electromagnetic field?

Comment: @oodNinja yes. This will, in turn, mean that it is possible for some light from outside to couple *into* the lossy cavity, but in general that will be negligible compared to the amount of light already in the cavity

Comment: I still don't understand. When I read research papers, there is mention of a lossy mode or a lossy cavity. And then treatment is theoretical. What does that mean?

Comment: @oodNinja this means that there is a physical mechanism for some of the light to escape from the mode or cavity in which you want it to remain

Comment: So a coupling with the electromagnetic field outside the cavity? Are you saying there will be two electromagnetic fields, (1) Inside the cavity and (2) outside?
And these will be independent of each other?

Comment: @oodNinja yes, in general this is always true... there can be electromagnetic fields in free space, for sure. You can also consider evanescent modes that will decay and lose energy within solids, for example

Comment: This answer should clarify that "loss" corresponds to coupling to a continuum of modes, or at least a very large number of other modes. Coupling to a single other mode isn't normally called "loss".

Comment: @DanielSank sure, updated, thanks. I wouldn't have been offended if you changed that in my answer

Comment: @QuantumMechanic ok I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Superconductors manifest lossless behaviour (in terms of EM energy preservation and zero heat generation) mostly in static situations with constant DC currents.

If the device is to do some information processing, its state will have to change in time, which means EM field and electric current changing in time. This opens the superconductor to various energy losses, partial breakdown of superconducting state, heat generation etc.

Comment: How would that look in the Hamiltonian of the cavity and the mode?

Comment: The common wisdom is that if there are energy losses, these cannot be described correctly via Hamiltonian description and instead, modifying the Hamiltonian equations of motion via new non-Hamiltonian terms to acquire dissipative behaviour is the easiest way. For example, an harmonic oscillator model is modified via additing additional equation term with first time derivative. The claim isn't completely true, as one can describe dissipative systems such as damped harmonic oscillator via special Hamiltonians. This is a broad and complicated topic.

Answer (score 0):

In short, "lossy" means a piece of (quantum) information/energy is lost in the system, and cannot be found back.

Let me use oscillator as an example. In superconducting quantum circuits, a cavity is a microwave oscillator which can be modeled as an electric oscillator. If the cavity is "lossless", which means this cavity has a quality factor Q of infinity. In other words, once excited, the oscillator will oscillate forever since there is no damping. On the contrary, if the cavity is "lossy", the oscillation will gradually decay. In terms of electric circuit, an LC oscillator is "lossless" and an RLC oscillator is "lossy".

I find the answer by @Quantum Mechanic may not be the 100% correct. Coupling to other modes doesn't necessarily make the system "lossy". For example, a two-qubit system where the two qubits are coupled to each other and information/energy can be exchanged between the two qubits. In this case, the coupling between the two-qubit system doesn't lead to information/energy loss.

A "lossy" mode means the information/energy cannot be restored, like spontaneous emission, radiation loss, heat dissipation, etc.